# xeditable jquery textarea has empty lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, x-editable

I'm using the x-editable jQuery plugin. It works great and everything looks fine except from the textarea when i try to edit a text. As soon as I hit the edit link or button the textarea appears with the text formated very strange. Also the cursor is always set to a position far away from the text end. I don't know how to tell x-editable that it should display the text correct.

[image: normal view]

[image: edit view]

```
$('a#editKommentar').editable({
    rows : 3,
    showbuttons : 'bottom',
    inputclass : 'boxsizingBorder',
    success : function(response, newText) {
        // do some stuff
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like an x-editable problem but more likely HTML hidding empty spaces (therefore, they only appear in the textarea form). What is saved in your db ? When you do see when you do a `<pre> <?=$textarea_content;?> </pre>`

Comment: the db just has the normal string without any empty spaces. I'll also tried the <pre> around the textarea_content but it didn't fixed the empty spaces.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: nope not yet! Project is on hold! Do you have the same problem?